# How to end a (double data type) input loop when 0 is inputed?

Tags: java

Basically, I want the user to be able to enter in a decimal number and then be reprompted as many times as they want until they enter in the number zero to exit the loop. rp is a double data type. However, I get an error that states "double cannot be converted to boolean"

```
while (true){
    rp = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter in double:"));
    if (rp = 0.0){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo. `rp == 0.0`; one `=` is assignment and then evaluates to the value on the right hand side.

Comment: Change to `if (rp == 0.0)`

Comment: Some people prefer to write `if (0.0 == rp)` because if you make the mistake of writing one equals sign `=`, it will give an error message instead of a warning.

Comment: @AntonH small green dudes who live on remote swamp planets, particularly. There's no need to do such a thing here: the compiler has rightly caught it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Right you are.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `do..while` loop with `!=` as comparison operator (instead of `=` as `=` is assignment operator), e.g.:

```
double rp;
do{
rp = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter in double:"));
//process
}while(rp != 0.0);
```

Comment: Note that the Double class has a .equals() method that can be used for the comparison.

Comment: I know, but OP is using `double` literal here, so `equals` does not apply unless we box it.

Answer (score 1):

In the if instruction you made an assignement.

You should write `if (rp == 0.0)` instead.

Comment: This is a brief answer, but it is definitely an answer, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has mentioned within their comments, you have accidently made a mistake within the if statement expression.

The solution below solves your problem by using the equality operator rather than the assignment operator.

```
while (true){
 rp = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter in double:"));
 if (rp == 0.0){  // double equals for checking equality
   break;
 }
}
```